# Include local folder in Docker container

Tags: python, docker

I have this structure:

```
ROOT
|
|--my_module
    | __init__.py
    | my_file.py
| Dockerfile
| app.py
```

Inside app.py is `from my_module import my_file` which is triggering a   `"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'my_module'",` which a) feels like a backwards error message to me, so maybe I'm misunderstanding, and b) I can't fix.

I've gone into the command line and seen that indeed, my_module is not included.  I've tried adding the following to my Dockerfile (separately):

`COPY app.py requirements.txt my_module/ ./`
and
`COPY my_module/ /usr/lib/python3.8/my_module/`

But no help, although the latter does at least include the my_module folder in the /usr directory.  Same error though, when I use it in the AWS console.  When I directly run the file in Docker, I get the similar error message of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 14, in <module>
    from my_module import my_file
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_module'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
RUN mkdir -p my_module
COPY app.py requirements.txt ./
COPY my_module/* my_module/
```

Comment: explaination would be useful. Namely that Docker will copy whats inside the module folder into the top level when used like in the question.

Comment: You can also leave the run instruction away. Docker will create the folder if it doesn't exists. The 2 copy commands are enough.

Answer (score -1):

You need to mount the volume, see: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Within your docker-compose file it would look something like this:
`version: "3.9" services: web: volumes: - root:/home/yourapp volumes: yourapp:`

Comment: no, there is no volume required. It could be done with volume but it doesnt have to. Otherwise how would you build a docker image that you can ship? Its about how dockers COPY instruction can be confusing.

Comment: Then try something like: `# Pull base image
FROM python:3.7
# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
# Set work directory
WORKDIR /code
# Install dependencies
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/
RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system
# Copy project
COPY . /code/` and then your docker compose: `version: '3.7'
services:
web:
build: .
command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
volumes:
- .:/code
ports:
- 8000:8000`. Sorry for the formatting, on mobile rn